# .htaccess catching mixed URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to match these three routes:

```
system/session
teams
teams/529f3d87b3f7e2c73d100000
```

I have the following rules:

```
RewriteRule ([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/([-A-Za]+)$ /index.php?__module=$1&__action=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?__module=$1&__action=index [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?__module=$1&__action=index&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

However, when I goto `system/session` its catching the rule set for `teams/529f3d87b3f7e2c73d100000` and making `session = $_GET['id']` and not `$_GET['__action']`

Is there an obvious solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your regex is wrong for the first rule:

```
RewriteRule ([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/([-A-Za-z]+)$ /index.php?__module=$1&__action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

You're missing the `-z` part of the range, and only matching "a".

You should also go ahead and add `^` matches to them all:

```
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/([-A-Za-z]+)$ /index.php?__module=$1&__action=$2 [L,QSA]
```